# Vs 2019 / Asp.net MVC / .Net framework 4.6.1 -> Ctrl + F5 keeps causing development computer crashes

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, windows, visual-studio-2019

Recently my development team has had issues with Visual Studio 2019/ Asp.net MVC / .NET framework 4.6.1 project.

When we `ctrl + F5` at random times our local development computer crashes due to memory issues. This doesn't happen every time, but randomly.

Has anyone seen this?

Visual Studio 2019 version: Version 16.10.2
Windows version: Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19041 Build 19041

Things we've tried:

1. Going back to the earlier version of VS 2019
2. Removed certain .css / .js scripts
3. Reordered our script rendering in our layout (was deferred)
4. Removed newer javascript that was added (which doesn't appear to be the issue)

Comment: do you mean that the *server* is crashing? or the browser?

Comment: @MarcGravell: My development computer. Everything appears fine in production with the actual application. Just when we develop.

Answer (score 0):

Appears our issue is due to a Windows update:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440339/kb5003637-and-the-new-kb5004476-gives-error-34fail.html#answer-447217

We will need to wait for an update to fix it.

Otherwise, remove the KB update and turn off auto updates.